# Angular Mat drag and drop detect when stop dragging over a div

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I am using angular material drag and drop and I have two lists like the drag and drag example from the docs. I would like to be able to drag one of the items over one of two divs and then snap back to the original list but detect which div it dropped over. I tried using the material dragEnded function but it only gives you X and Y coordinates. Is there anyway to get the id of the div the item was ended dragging over?

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>To do</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList, div1, div2]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item.value}}</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>
  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList,  div1, div2]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)">
      {{item.value}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div cdkDropList
     #div1="cdkDropList"
     [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
     style="background-color: red; width: 300px; height: 100px"
     id="div1"
>Div 1</div>
<br />
<div cdkDropList
     #div2="cdkDropList"
     [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
     style="background-color: red; width: 300px; height: 100px"
     id="div2"
>Div 2</div>
```

Comment: I answered a similar question before, Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555028/ng2-dragula-drag-and-drop-into-iframe/58555663#58555663)

Answer (score 1):

in the event `(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)` you has an event [CdkDrapDop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop)

In `event.container.data`and `event.currentIndex` you has the "data", you can add a "fool data" `[cdkDropListData]="'one'"`, `[cdkDropListData]="'two'"` and make a

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
       if (event.container.data=='one'){...}
       if (event.container.data=='two'){...}
    }
  }
```

If you has real data -an array, you can use `if (event.container.data==myarrayOne)`